Ternary operation not working with unary operation
I am sharing a simple SystemVerilog code where the ternary operation is misbehaving because of the reduction or ("|b") operation. I know many other work arounds. I just wanted to know what's going wrong here under the hood.
module tb();
  bit signed [0:3] a = 5;
  bit signed [0:3] b = -3;
  bit [0:1] op;
  
  bit signed [0:4] result;
  
  initial begin
    op = 0;
    result = 0;
    result = (op == 0)? a+b : (op == 1)? a-b: (op == 2)? ~a : |b;
    $display("%0p %0p %0p", result, a, b);
    
    op = 1;
    result = 0;
    result = (op == 0)? a+b : (op == 1)? a-b: (op == 2)? ~a : |b;
    $display("%0p %0p %0p", result, a, b);
    
    op = 2;
    result = 0;
    result = (op == 0)? a+b : (op == 1)? a-b: (op == 2)? ~a : |b;
    $display("%0b %0b %0p", result, a, b);
    
    op = 3;
    result = 0;
    result = (op == 0)? a+b : (op == 1)? a-b: (op == 2)? a : |b;
    $display("%0p %0p %0p", result, a, b);
  end

endmodule

I am sharing the code here. I am sure that the unary operation is to blame here. if I put only "b" instead of "|b" it will work as expected.

The problem with your code is both the different bit lengths and mixing signed and unsigned operands in the same expression.
In almost all binary operations, i op j, the operands i and j are transformed in context with one another. That means if the operands are of different lengths, the smaller one gets 0-extended or signed-extended. Sign extension only happens if all operands in that context are signed. The extension of operands happens before applying the operator.
With ternary operator i ? j : k, i is self-determined and is not in context with j and k which are with each other. The left-hand-side of an assignment is in context with its right-hand-side.
In your example, result is a 5-bit signed variable, and the variables a and b are both 4-bit signed variables. That means all operands need to be extended to 5-bits. However, with the operation |b, b is self determined but its result is 1-bit unsigned. That result becomes an unsigned operand to the ternary operator, that means the entire expression context is unsigned. So b gets zero-extended instead of sign-extended.
Section 11.8.2 Steps for evaluating an expression in the IEEE 1800-2023 SystemVerilog LRM goes over this in detail.
You could work around this problem if

all your variables were the same size eliminating the need for extensions
cast any unsigned operands to signed (but be careful as these operands will now get sign-extended)
use intermediate variables
use a case statement instead of deeply nested ternary operators


Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 11. Operators and expressions, especially sections:

11.6 Expression bit lengths
11.8 Expression evaluation rules

The difference between b and |b is bit length.  b is 4 bits, and the expression |b is 1 bit.  The bit length of any subexpression can affect the bit length of the full expression.

I know many other work arounds.

The complicated expression with several ternary operators is hard to understand and maintain.  The recommended coding style is to use a case statement.

The issue is that '|b' is unsigned. According to the standard, in this case, evaluation of the whole expression will be unsigned.
To fix the issue you need to make it 'signed' also. One of the way is to use a signed cast:
   result = (op == 0)? a+b : (op == 1)? a-b: (op == 2)? ~a : signed'(|b);
   $display("%0p %0p %0p", result, a, b);


Yes that fixed it. But I am still puzzled to understand why would that affect the addition and subtraction part. I tried to make some sense analyzing the precedence but still could not figure out.

Your result is 5 bit wide while, operands are 4 and 1.  Before doing any computation a verilog compiler will match widths, in this case it extends all operands to size '5' as required by the size of the result. But, in case of unsigned expressions, operands will be 0-extended, while in the signed expressions they will be sign-extended. Therefore 0101 (5) will be extended to 00101 (in both signed and unsigned);  1101(-3) will be extended to 01101(unsigned) and to 11101(signed). In signed world 00101(5) + 11101(-3) = 00010 (2); while in unsigned world 00101(5) + 01101(13)  = 10010(18)
